getReferencesTo returning None in Ghidra API (GhidraBridge)
I'm having a problem with the Ghidra API's getReferencesTo method in a Python script. When I try to retrieve references to a specific address in the binary, the method systematically returns None and type None when i try to transform it into a list, or simply to convert it.
The getReferencesTo method is called with a valid address.
The method returns None instead of a list of references.
Attempts to convert the result into a list do not resolve the problem, as the method continues to return None.

here's a brief description of my function :
def find_references_to_string(string_address):
    references = getReferencesTo(string_address)

####

references = list(references)


trying to display what the getReferencesTo function alone gives me, here's an example with a valid address:
Type of reference: <class 'jfx_bridge.bridge._bridged_array.array'>

Found %s references to address %s (4, <_bridged_ghidra.program.model.address.GenericAddress('00103096', type=ghidra.program.model.address.GenericAddress, handle=804c8712-c85e-4206-b28e-77ec377ceb63)>)

I use GhidraBridge.
Thanks a lot !
